# How to show the diameter in the graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a complete graph G with 5 nodes and I have to find the diameter of the G (randomly selected node ) and also draw this diameter in the red colour. How can I do that with Networkx and Python? These are my attempts. Also I need to say there were more of them but the only difference is instead of shortest path I tried to use other functions(subgraph, algorythms, etc.) Also, I need to explain that random node means that you choose a start for the diameter randomly

```
import networkx as nx  #1 attempt

G = nx.complete_graph(5)

dg = nx.shortest_path(G)

edge_colors = ['red' if e in dg.edges else 'black' for e in G.edges]

nx.draw(G, edge_color=edge_colors)






def get_diameters(graph):   #attempt 2


diams = []
for g in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph):
    diams.append(nx.diameter(g))
diams = list(filter(lambda a: a != 0, diams))
return np.array(diams) Graph.number_of_nodes()
```

Comment: Please show your attempts. Also, explain what does it mean "randomly selected node." The graph diameter does not depend on choosing nodes.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't but it matters when you need to draw it, like I do

Comment: In a random (not complete) graph, a randomly chosen node does not necessarily belong to one of the longest geodesics.

Comment: It is true, but I need to find an algorithm that will find diameter and show it on a graph, so in this particular task I should make it random.

Comment: To clarify - your task is to select a random node, then find the longest shortest path from that node to another node, and draw those edges in red? What is your expected output with the complete graph? To plot a random edge in red?

Comment: Basically, yes. But, given that anyone can paint their edge in red I decided to look for an algorithm for any randomly selected node in the connected graph with what I have failed.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you're not looking for the diameter of the graph itself, but for the longest shortest path in a graph given a random starting node. This can be achieved using `nx.shortest_path` with the `source` keyword argument, giving it a random starting node. We can look through the resultant dictionary, find the longest shortest path, and plot the edges which form this path in red.

### Code

```
import networkx as nx
import random

# Create graph
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10, 0.3)

# Pick a random node
source = random.choice(list(G.nodes))

# Find the longest shortest path from the node
shortest_paths = nx.shortest_path(G, source=source)
target = max(shortest_paths, key=lambda i: len(shortest_paths[i]))
l_s_path = shortest_paths[target]
l_s_path_edges = list(zip(l_s_path, l_s_path[1:]))

# Draw the graph, then draw over the required edges in red.
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, edge_color='r', edgelist=l_s_path_edges, pos=pos)
```

### Output

Note that in this example, the diameter of the graph is 4; the longest shortest path is from node 6 to node 4. The randomly selected source node was 7 - the longest shortest path from node 7 is of length 3.

[image]